# How to click on an input type submit with no defined ID using Selenium WebDriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to website, the login form doesn't have any ids associated with its value, and it uses only names:

```
<div id="warp">
<div id="content">
<form action="/index.php" method="post" name='login'>
username: <input type="text" name="username">
password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="login" class="submit" value="login">
```

using the following commands I am able to fill in the user ID and password, but I can't click submit.

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
username.sendKeys("xxxxx");
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
password.sendKeys("xxxxx");
```

this doesn't get executed:

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.name("login"));
login.click();
```

Error :-

> Unable to locate element login

And if I did element.submit();
it clears out the entered data in the pass/user fields.

Comment: Make sure this login button is not inside any frame or iframe??

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm seeing in your provided HTML, there is two elements present with same name `login`, you need to create more specific your locator to locate `login` button using `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.submit[name = 'login']"))).click();
```

Comment: This did it!! Thank you so much!! qq, the name 'login' associated with the form or the input field?

Comment: It associated with both but provided answer just locate to login button input field. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it put things into prospective. I am new to WebDriver so thanks for your clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

```
element.submit()
```

There is a method provided in selenium API to submit form details
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms

From the doc, extracted info for you:

> Once you’ve finished filling out the form, you probably want to submit
>   it. One way to do this would be to find the “submit” button and click
>   it:
>
> driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
>
> Alternatively, WebDriver has the convenience method “submit” on every
>   element. If you call this on an element within a form, WebDriver will
>   walk up the DOM until it finds the enclosing form and then calls
>   submit on that. If the element isn’t in a form, then the
>   NoSuchElementException will be thrown:
>
> element.submit();

Comment: Please let us know if that doesn't helps you

Comment: Unable to locate element  method "id" selector "submit"

Comment: FYI `.submit()` works on from element to submit the form instead, don't confuse with submit button. you should suggest to OP perform it on form element instead of submit button. And also keep it in mind OP unable to locate button element instead of unable to click. Thank

Comment: @Moe: You mentioned, "the login form doesn't have any ids"  Isn't it a form.? Also, the selenium doc says, if you want to submit any form  alternatively, there is a submit() method on all elements, and if you want to submit any form simply call  "element.submit()" (Note: NOT click() method, you are calling login.click(), instead try, login.submit())

Comment: when I use .submit, it clears out my form. I updated the question of how the form looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 elements with `name='login'` try to identify the element uniquely using any of the unique attributes or using multiple attributes.

Using **CSS**:

```
"input[value='login']"
```

---

Using **XPath**:

```
"input[@value='login']"<br>
"input[@value='login' and @type='submit']"
```